# How do I call some blocking method with a timeout in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a standard nice way to call a blocking method with a timeout in Objective C?  I want to be able to do:

```
// call [something blockingMethod];
// if it hasn't come back within 2 seconds, forget it
```

Thanks.

Comment: In real life you’ll never block, so is this purely academic? If you were truly blocked, how could your code that doesn’t run “decide” to resume in 2 seconds? Is it alive and dead at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to interrupt a function that is not designed to be interrupted. Doing so would generally cause data corruption and resource leaks.

The standard way to achieve what you're describing is to redesign `blockingMethod` so that it accepts a timeout or other cancelation mechanism.

If that's not possible, and it is required that you timeout `blockingMethod`, the standard approach is to fork a child process to run `blockingMethod`, and kill it (usually by sending SIGTERM) if it doesn't finish by the timeout. This is somewhat complex to implement in ObjC, and you'll need to also implement a mechanism to send the results back to the parent process. Since the operating system manages resources (memory, file handles, etc) at the process level, the only way to forcibly interrupt a function is to create a separate process for it. This still can lead to data corruption depending on what `blockingMethod` does, but it will work for a much larger set of problems.

Note that it's not generally possible to fork a process from non-Apple code on iOS, so this can't be done there.

As an example of what I mean by "data corruption," consider some simple code like:

```
[self.cache lock];
[self.cache removeObject: object];
[self.cache decrementCountOfObjects];
[self.cache unlock];
```

Now imagine that the process were forcibly terminated in the middle of this operation. What should happen? How does the cache get unlocked? How are the cache contents and the count reconciled? It's even possible that the object would be in the middle of being copied; then what? How would the system automatically deal with all of these issues unless `blockingMethod` were written with cancelation in mind?

Answer (score 4):

How about using a semaphore? This can be locked across threads and then you can do something like

```
dispatch_semaphore_t s = dispatch_semaphore_create ( 0 );

// In a different thread or on some queue,
// fire up some process, when done signal
// the semaphore with
[ fire up thread ... some task, when done
dispatch_semaphore_signal( s );
... ]

// This waits 2 seconds for the semaphore
if ( dispatch_semaphore_wait( s, 2 ) )
{
  // ... it hasn't come back after 2 seconds so 'forget it'
}
else
{
  // ... you now have the semaphore within 2 seconds so 'do it'
}

// This waits forever, just for reference
dispatch_semaphore_wait( s, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER );
```

Comment: This is a good solution for continuing on after two seconds if the called method doesn't return, but it doesn't "forget it" in the sense of cancelling the called method. It might be fine to just let that method continue, but it might also not be fine, e.g. if the method uses significant resources or otherwise gets in the way of the process.

Comment: Especially imagine if the process eventually *does* complete. Then some operation may be done twice, or in a surprising order. It's quite possible to design systems where that's fine (i.e. idempotent), but it doesn't work in general.

Comment: Set a flag to prevent doing some operation twice and semaphore is exactly what you can use to ensure order so I don't think this is a big or non-standard problem.Here I assume 'something' needs to be done if process completes after 2 seconds otherwise not, which is what OP asked for.

Comment: ... also, Caleb, use a flag to stop the running process if that is what 'forget' means. Set the flag after 2 seconds if the process is not done and inside the process check this flag periodically and exit if set. Flag must be atomic or synchronised on something of course.